# How do I insert multiple dynamic input into excel cell?

Tags: excel

I am trying to create a form in excel, the majority of the input fields are optional, but some will have 1 or many.
For example services can be cleaning, driving.
A person can have multiple contact numbers.
and multiple email addresses.

most of the examples I have seen have 1 to 1 mapping when creating a form.

I'm stuck in trying to create dynamic form objects if there are multiple inputs, and storing repeatable values in a single cell.

This is the shape of the data.

```
ID - 16 digit number

SERVICES repeatable
SERVICES - example cleaning, driving, cooking.

1 ADDRESS
2 ADDRESS
CITY 
POSTCODE

PHONE NUMBER repeatable
PHONE NUMBER 01234-45555555
PHONE NUMBER 01234-45555556

EMAIL repeatable
EMAIL joe@jobs.com
EMAIL jo2@jobs.com
```

I might have a solution for saving multiple values to a single cell by concatenating the inputs. My issue is I don't know how many I will have to begin with.
I can hardcode to lets say 4 but I might have more.

What would be the best approach to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few interesting options in Excel to account for dynamic content length and limited user manipulation.

One way would be to have some kind of Macro (VBA) to either trigger on adding values in these repeatable fields or force the users to client on a button to add more lines. There is no way to have a cell automatically "know" it should create a new line under itself to account for more values.

Another would be to not add dynamism but rather account for an amount of records you do not expect you will get (e.g. 10 phone numbers) and leave that space. This is probably the most stable solution although in the instances where you would need 11+ phone numbers you would probably end up missing data or have the user input multiple phone numbers in one cell (which might happen anyway).

In any case, it's rarely advisable to concatenate multiple values in a single field as it becomes a mess to process.

Comment: That was my idea as well, to have additional fields, it just looked janky. 
Seems to be the simplest solution.